# Awestruct: generate html page that lists all files in a directory

Tags: ruby, haml, awestruct

In our Awestruct website, we have a directory like this:

```
/xsd
    /foo_1_0.xsd
    /foo_1_1.xsd
    /foo_1_2.xsd
    /foo_1_3.xsd
    ...
    /index.haml
```

That `index.haml` gives some information on how to use a `foo*.xsd` file. I'd like that `index.haml` also to list all xsd files, without hardcoding them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and it will lists all the directory content as an array:

```
 Dir.entries(".")
     #=> [".", "..", "file1", "file2"]
```

You can change the `.` with your directory path.